# WCF routing backuplists - logging when they are used

Tags: wcf, endpoints, wcf-endpoint, wcf-routing

Is there anyway to add some logging or a behaviour to the WCF routing list so that I can log when the routing has made use of an endpoint on a backup list?

```
     <filterTables>
        <filterTable name="RoutingTable">
          <add filterName="Filter1" endpointName="EP1" priority="0" backupList="FailOver"/>
        </filterTable>
      </filterTables>
      <backupLists>
        <backupList name="FailOver">
          <add endpointName="EP2" />
        </backupList>
      </backupLists>
```

Could a behaviour somehow log which endpoint had finally been used by the routing service?

Comment: Not sure you have an extensibility point for that. But you can use AppFabric for monitoring your client/service. In addition, you can implement a custom message filter that logs the result.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a service behavior (or endpoint behavior and configure the behavior on all endpoints)

hook up a message inspector IClientMessageInspector

pass in the endpoint in a constructor

log the message and the endpoint on the BeforeSendRequest method

```
public class MyClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    private ServiceEndpoint _endpoint;

    public MyClientMessageInspector(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        _endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        Log(request, _endpoint);
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        //no-op
    }
}
```

then you want to apply the inspector to a behavior and attach to the **router**